# Call agent asynchronously Xpages

Tags: xpages

I get this code to Thread and Jobs application on OpenNTF.org

```java
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.IJobChangeEvent;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.JobChangeAdapter;

import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor;

public class JobRunner {

public static void start(String dbPath, String agentName, String paramDocId) {

    synchronized (JobRunner.class) {

        runningJob = new ISPJob(dbPath, agentName, paramDocId);
        runningJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
            public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Done event");
                runningJob = null;
            }
        });
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            public Object run() {
                runningJob.schedule();
                return null;
            }
        });

    }
}

private static ISPJob runningJob;

private static final class ISPJob extends Job {

    private ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus> executor;

    private String docId;
    private String dbPath;
    private String agentName;

    public ISPJob(String paramDbPath, String paramAgentName, String paramDocId) {
        super(paramDocId);

        this.docId = paramDocId;
        this.dbPath = paramDbPath;
        this.agentName = paramAgentName;

        this.executor = new ThreadSessionExecutor<IStatus>() {
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(Session session) throws NotesException {

                System.out.println("Job started" + docId);
                System.out.println("   >> Session created: "
                        + session.getUserName() + ", Effective User:"
                        + session.getEffectiveUserName());

                    Database db = session.getDatabase(null,dbPath);

                    if (db != null) {
                        try {
                            if (!db.isOpen()) db.open();
                            if (db.isOpen()) {
                                System.out.println("   >> Database opened: "
                                        + db.getTitle());
                                Agent agent = db.getAgent(agentName);
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("   >> Agent Started: " + agent.getName());
                                    agent.run(docId);
                                    System.out.println("   >> Agent Ran: " + agent.getName());
                                } finally {
                                    agent.recycle();
                                }

                            }
                        } finally {
                            db.recycle();                           
                        }

                }
                System.out.println("Job completed");

                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }
        };

    }

    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        try {
            return executor.run();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return Status.CANCEL_STATUS;
        }
    }
};
}
```

I used the code (`JobRunner` class) in a `onclick` event on a button (SSJS)

```xml
   <xp:button value="Label" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="button4">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:myPck.JobRunner.start(database.getFilePath(),"(Export)",docTemp.getUniversalID())}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Returns me the following error

```
"Error 500 http web server command not handled exception"
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: just out of curiosity, do you have "Display XPage runtime error Page" checked in the Xsp Properties page? If not, you might be able to see some extra information if you do.

Comment: It's a dumb question, but I have to ask: is your package just named "myPck", and not something like "com.company.myPck"?

Comment: What is you Domino version?

Comment: I have check the "Display XPage runtime error Page".
Yes..My package si "com.company.myPck".
Domino is 9.0.1

Comment: @user3873177: I'm a little confused because you marked your question as answered by Serdar Basegmez but also added another answer stating that changing the permissions didn't solve the problem. In case the problem is still unsolved, you should use "com.company.myPck.JobRunner.start(...)" instead of "myPck.JobRunner.start(...)" on your XPage. If you do not explicitely import the package in SSJS, you always need to call it with the complete package name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are experiencing `ClassNotFoundException` for Eclipse runtime classes (in workspace/logs folder), it means that XPages prevent you to use those classes for security. Normally, granting all permissions using java.policy file should solve this problem.

However, I have experienced buggy and inconsistent behviour in `ThreadSessionExecuter` class for different Domino versions. I have also tested your code on 9.0.1 and had such an issue on my test server as well.

You might use an alternative approach. You might refer to my blog entry that contains links to the demo database and slide deck from ICONUK 2013.

http://lotusnotus.com/lotusnotus_en.nsf/dx/iconuk-2013-slidedeck-demo-application-and-a-surprize....htm

Also check [XPages Toolkit](http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20Toolkit) project from OpenNTF. It provides a plugin framework for running background tasks.

Answer (score -1):

Into my log i have an  "ClassNotFoundException",
i have modify my file java.policy and restart the server but the error 500 continue

C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Domino\jvm\lib\security

```
// Notes java code gets all permissions

grant codeBase "file:${notes.binary}/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${notes.binary}/rjext/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${notes.binary}/ndext/*" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${notes.binary}/xsp/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

grant codeBase "file:${notes.binary}/osgi/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};


// My new line
grant {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```